# Show text block under an image block on clicking the image block

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to have a image block overlaying a text block i.e. image block on a text block
When I click in the image it should display the text block and image block becomes hidden (may be to expand the text block more to show contents).

Note the text div should be invisible under image div and on clicking the image it should show up and image will hide:

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(function(){ 
    $('.close').click(function(){ 
        $('#textDiv').show(); 
        $('#imageDiv').hide(); 
    }); 
 })
```

HTML:

```
<div id="imageDiv" >
   <a href="#" class="close">Close <img src="images/close.png" class="close"></a>
</div> 

<div id="textDiv" style="display:none;">This is the text for the image </div>
```

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? Do you have any code?

Comment: Thanks for your response - Note the text div should be invisible under image div and on clicking the image it should show up and image will hide 
 
        $(function(){
            $('.close').click(function(){
             
                $('#textDiv').show();
                $('#imageDiv').hide();
            });
        })

  
<div id="imageDiv" ><a href="#" class="close">Close <img src="images/close.png" class="close"></a></div>

<div id="textDiv" style="display:none;">This is the text for the image </div>

Answer (score 0):

You want like this, check DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/gNQVR/1/

## JQUERY

```
$('#imageDiv img').on('click', function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).siblings('#textDiv').show();
});
$('#textDiv .close').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent('#textDiv').hide();
    $(this).parent().siblings('img').show();
});
```

## HTML

```
<div id="imageDiv" >
   <img src="http://wallpaper-fullhd.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/at-the-beach-hd-wallpaper-1920x1200.jpg" class="close" width="200" height="200">
   <div id="textDiv">
       <a class="close">x</a>
       This is the text for the image. ...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks- This is partly satisfies my requirement but instead of toggle effect I need to have close button on the text block which will close the text box and also a scrollbar included in the text block will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rBxeY/

```
$('div').click(function(){
   $('div').toggleClass('active'); 
});
```

html

```
<div id="imageDiv" class="active">
    <a href="#" class="close">Close <img src="images/close.png" class="close" /></a>
</div> 

<div id="textDiv" >This is the text for the image </div>
```

css

```
.active{
    display: none;
}
```